# "notlike" not working as expected in while loop using a file name

Tags: powershell

Having the toughest time over something seemingly so small. I want to stay in the while loop while the file is not in the folder, when it is found and the file name is similar, then come out.

```
$path = "\\xxx\yyy\"

function getFileName{
$file = Get-ChildItem –Path $path | Where-object -property Name -like "UserFile*"
$file = $file.Name
}

getFileName

while($file -notlike 'UserFile*'){
Write-Warning "User file not found, ensure it is in the root folder of the LAN Share..."
Read-Host "Press enter when the file is in the root folder to continue..."

getFileName
}
```

Comment: [The `$file` variable inside the `getFileName` function **stops existing as soon as the function stops executing**.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes)

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$founded=Get-ChildItem $path -file -Filter "UserFile*" | select -first 1

if($founded)
{
    $result=Read-Host "Press enter when the file is in the root folder to continue..."
}
else
{
    Write-Warning "User file not found, ensure it is in the root folder of the LAN Share..."
}
```